# Any real usage of realtime signal in Unix?

Tags: unix, signals, real-time

Are there any situations when it worth to use realtime signals for interprocess communication(or any other reason actually)? 
For me it seems like all the difficulties with them make the code overcomplicated, difficult to maintain and potentially full of bugs.

It would be nice if somebody could show that I'm mistaken.

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notably, realtime signals are used internally in the NPTL implementation of [pthreads](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).

Realtime signals, unlike their basic counterparts, will queue, making them useful for [edge-triggered IO readiness indication](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html#nb.sigio).

Realtime signals, unlike their basic counterparts, can also carry an `int`/pointer's worth of arbitrary data.  I can think of several times I've wanted to send just a bit more data along with a notification.

I'm not sure what you mean by "overcomplicated, difficult to maintain and potentially full of bugs."